# Examine where $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is partial differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Given,
>
> $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R,$
>
> $f(x, y)$ $:=$ $x^3 \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus 0,$
>
> $f(x, y) := 0, (x, y) = 0,$
>
> I have to examine where the function is partial differentiable.

**Approach**

In order to get a feeling of the task, I would start with examining partial differentiability in $(0, 0)$. Using the definition of the differential quotient and treating $y$ as a constant first, I would have to show that

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ $({(x + h)^3 \over \sqrt{(x + h)^2 + y^2}}$ $-$ $x^3 \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$)  $1 \over h$

does indeed exist. I guess that I would have to put $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, but I can't do that since this would give me a $0$ in the right denominanter. So, do I have to write this differently first? Or is the approach false?

**Edit after discussion in the comments**

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ $({(x + h)^3 \over \sqrt{(x + h)^2 + y^2}}$ $-$ $x^3 \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$)  $1 \over h$ $=$

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ $({(0 + h)^3 \over \sqrt{(0 + h)^2 + 0}}$ $-$ $0 \over \sqrt{0 + 0}$)  $1 \over h$ $=$

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ $h^3 \over \sqrt{h^2}$ $*$ $1 \over h$ $=$

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ $h^2$ * $1 \over h$ $=$

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ $h $= $0$.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. The $h$ needs to be inside the power function on $x$. $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} ({(x+h)^3  \over \sqrt{(x+h)^2 + y^2}}$ $-$ $x^3 \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$)  $1 \over h$

Comment: That's a good point, thank you very much! But what do I do about the denominator of the right fraction regarding the problem mentioned above? :-)

Comment: Nothing. It's fine as it is. You need to compute this limit for your answer. You can do this easily on Wolfram Alpha or by hand.

Comment: I made an edit in the main post with my solution - may you have a look at it? :-)

Comment: Furthermore, if I do the same while treating $x$ as a constant, I would get $1 \over h$, and the critical value of this is obviously not the same as the one that I calculated before. Therefore, the function is not partial differentiable in (0, 0), is it? Or isn't is necessary for the critical values to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that $f$ admits its partial derivatives on the punctured plane. It thus suffices to consider the point $(0,0)$. What you say in your edit is true. The "putting in 0" problem is resolved as follows: you want to evaluate $f$ at $0$. But by definition this $0$. You are right in that $\partial f/\partial x(0)$ exists.

To show the existence of $\partial f/\partial y(0)$ you note that $f(0,-)=0$ identically. For that reason the denominator in the definition of partial differentiabilty is $0$.

Comment: Thanks. :-) What would be the next step here? There must be other points that I have to examine, but how do I know at which of those I have to look at?

Comment: @Julian: all other points are contained in $\mathbf{R}^2-0$. But by definition the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbf{R}^2-0$ is given by $g(x,y)=x^3/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Now do you agree that 1) the denominator admits all partial derivatives, 2) the nominator admits all partial derivatives (.. chain rule), 3) a quotient of functions admitting all partial derivatives admits all partial derivatives (...quotient rule)?

Comment: One of the most important things to know about differentiability is that it is a LOCAL property, i.e. you can check it (by definition) in any neighborhood, however small. This means that for all points in $\mathbf{R}^2-0$ you can ignore the value of $f$ at $0$. The difficulty of this problem lies in the differentiability at the origin.

Comment: We didn't apply the chain rule or quotient rule on functions with more than one variable yet, so there must be another way of working on this problem.

Comment: @Julian one doesn't need a chain rule, it just the chain rule for functions of one variable... without knowing this you basically can't compute partial derivatives reasonably. so you can assume this for sure

Comment: You mean I should treat $x^3$, $x^2$, $y^2$ and the square root like they were functions themselves? Then I would have the two continious functions $x^2$ and $y^2$ in the denominator, such that $x^2 + y^2$ is continious too, and therefore, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ would be the continiuous too. (chain rule)

Comment: No. What I mean is the following: let $p=(p_x,p_y)$ be a point in the plane. Consider the function $g:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ by $g(z)=f(z,p_y)$. By writing out the defintions you see that the partial deriative $\partial f/\partial x(p)$ is the same as $g'(p_x)$.

Comment: @Julian it is a pleasure. When people (like you did above) say that the partial derivatives are computed "by holding y constant", then what they actually mean is just what I said.